# Letting VBA convert different date formats

Tags: vba, date, excel

I've got a VBA macro which reads Excel files and needs to process the data in there, including some dates. However, depending on the user who exported these files, the dates in those sheets might be written `YYYYMMDD`, `MM/DD/YYYY`, `DD.MM.YYYY`, `M/D/YYYY` and so on. All are only formatted as text.

So far, I've tried parsing the string and creating a new date. As I encounter more exotic dates, like `M/DD/YYYY` or `D.MM.YY`, my code gets very large and doesn't seem very elegant. I've searched, but I couldn't find any standardised way or function to detect these several date formats and convert them accordingly.

Am I missing something or is simply parsing the string the only reliable way for doing this?

Comment: what would `MM/DD/YYY` look like? are you missing a `Y`?

Comment: I would suggest you store dates as dates ( Excel stores them as numbers ) instead of `Strings` so you can just take `ActiveCell.Value` and convert to actual date.

Comment: I'm not aware of any library taking care of that. Best option in my opinion would be to use a RegEx library - and test a regex for each potential date format. This would most likely be the "cleanest" code...

Comment: mehow: You're right. I indeed meant MM/DD/YYYY. Thankfully, it doesn't get as strange as MM/DD/YYY.

Comment: @JulianB you can only automate half of the process of converting the dates. Some of the dates for example `M/D/YYYY` may appear as `07/08/2013` which could be dually interpreted depending on the locale settings. This could *without error* create a `M/D/YYYY` or `D/M/YYYY` converting to a wrong date. Is there any way to go back to the file with raw data and re-format cells to store dates as dates and not Strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code - it'll convert any of the following formats: `DD.MM.YYYY`,`DD.MM.YY`,`YYYYMMDD`,`MM/DD/YYYY`,`MM/DD/YY`,`M/D/YYYY`, `M/D/YY`.

You can easily add additional formats, just add more conversion rules to the `If...ElseIf...` statement.

```
Option Explicit

Private mStrLastPattern As String
Private mStrSourceDate As String
Private mDatResult As Date

Public Function fctDateFromString(strDate As String) As Date
    mStrSourceDate = strDate
    mDatResult = 0
    If TryConvert("(^\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})$", "$2/$1/$3") Then       'DD.MM.YYYY
    ElseIf TryConvert("(^\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})$", "$2/$1/20$3") Then 'DD.MM.YY
    ElseIf TryConvert("(^\d{4})(\d{2})\.(\d{2})$", "$2/$3/$1") Then     'YYYYMMDD
    ElseIf TryConvert("(^\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})$", "$1/$2/$3") Then     'MM/DD/YYYY
    ElseIf TryConvert("(^\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$", "$1/$2/20$3") Then   'MM/DD/YY
    ElseIf TryConvert("(^\d{1})/(\d{1})/(\d{4})$", "0$1/0$2/$3") Then   'M/D/YYYY
    ElseIf TryConvert("(^\d{1})/(\d{1})/(\d{2})$", "0$1/0$2/20$3") Then 'M/D/YY
    End If
    If mDatResult = 0 Then Debug.Print "Cannot find matching format for " & strDate
    fctDateFromString = mDatResult
End Function

Private Function TryConvert(strFrom As String, strTo As String) As Boolean
    If RegExMatch(strFrom) Then
        mDatResult = RegExConvert("$1/$2/$3")
        TryConvert = (mDatResult <> 0)
    End If
End Function

Private Function RegExMatch(strPattern As String) As Boolean
    mStrLastPattern = strPattern
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = strPattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        RegExMatch = .Test(mStrSourceDate)
    End With
End Function

Private Function RegExConvert(strReplacePattern As String) As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = mStrLastPattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        RegExConvert = CDate(.Replace(mStrSourceDate, strReplacePattern))
        If Err.Number Then
            Err.Clear
            RegExConvert = 0
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Note, that this code will  interpret `MM.DD.YYYY` as `DD.MM.YYYY` and so on as long as the number of digits matches and the resulting date is valid.

Comment: +1 for RegEx, which is always as awesome as a neutron star for situations like this. :)